# Linux command line interface in VirtualBox: how to automatically adjust to the window size?

Tags: linux, command-line, virtualbox, grub, resolution

Following [my struggle to adjust the resolution of a CLI Ubuntu minimal guest in VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017218/ubuntu-minimal-in-virtualbox-cant-get-fullscreen-resolution/48022841#48022841), I have been trying to find a way to automatically adjust the resolution to the window size. This should be doable because for example when you open terminal in Ubuntu (or other UniX like GUI OSes), it automatically adjusts to the windows size automatically.

**What I'm not looking for:**

I already know how to adjust the resolution to any of the available options in the `GRUB>vbeinfo` by editing the `/etc/default/grub` as explained in [my former SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017218/ubuntu-minimal-in-virtualbox-cant-get-fullscreen-resolution/48022841#48022841)

**What I need:**

The CLI to automatically adjust to the window size. for example when I exit fullscreen it gets smaller to fit the window. This behaviour already exists in GUI interfaces (Unity and GNOME...)

**GNU documentation:**

[GNU documentation page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration) states:

> grub-mkconfig will normally load all available GRUB video drivers

and

> Note that you can only use modes which your graphics card supports via VESA BIOS Extensions (VBE), so for example native LCD panel resolutions may not be available.

Comment: Please clarify: What window size do you want to adjust? The size of the VirtualBox window on your host machine? Or the resolution of the display of the guest OS to fit the size of the VirtualBox window? Or the size of any window within the guest OS?

Comment: @LukeLR  The second option `the resolution of the display of the guest OS to fit the size of the VirtualBox window` I want a headless only CLI linux guest to adjust to the size of virtualbox window. the first one is already there, but the geus OS does not adjust. The third option I do not understand.